# How do I make grunt watch compass while keeping an express server up?

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs, watch

I understand how to make grunt watch the sass files for changes then compile and how to start an express server as well but I can't figure out how to keep an express server running while watching changes for sass files. I've been googling for an hour and have given up, is this an impossible task? I'm new to grunt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you take a look at Nodemon? https://github.com/remy/nodemon

> nodemon will watch the files in the directory where nodemon was started, and if they change, >it will automatically restart your node application.

Does integrate with grunt: https://github.com/ChrisWren/grunt-nodemon